# Why can outside-scope variables change inside an iterator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
value = 2

def change
  value = 3
end

puts value

3.times do
  value = 0
end
puts value
```

produces 2, 0. Why can the iterator change the outside-of-scope variable? How can I make sure it doesn't change it?

Comment: read here http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/using-ruby-blocks-and-rolling-your-own-iterators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks have access to the container scope. To prevent accessing `value` in the block you can use a block local var like so

```
value = 2

def change
  value = 3
end

puts value

3.times do |;value|
  value = 0
end
puts value
```

See [this](http://www.ghendry.net/scoperb.html) nice writeup on ruby scopes

Comment: *+1* for giving the Nice Link!!

Answer (score -1):

That's because the code that gets evaluated in each iteration between the `do` and the `end` is expressed with an instance of a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html) (they're called blocks or closures).

From the Ruby documentation:

> Proc objects are blocks of code that have been bound to a set of local
>   variables. Once bound, the code may be called in different contexts
>   and still access those variables.

By definition you can't avoid changing these references from inside the block.